# React navigation 5.x after login redirect on a specific screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I am working on a hotel booking app where I have to apply a condition, on the time of hotel booking if a user is not loggedIn, there will be a button login to book, when the user will click on a button it will redirect to the login screen after login, I want it should be redirected on same hotel booking screen, but right now after login it redirects to the home screen. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

When User click the Button it will redirect to the login screen...Then Your can Pass a Props value like
this.props.navigation.navigate('login',{BackTopage:"bookingpage"})

Now When click login Button just check the Props Using If condition
if(this.props.navigation.state.params .BackTopage == 'bookingpage'){
this.props.navigation.navigate('BookingPage')
}

Answer (score 0):

//for navigation 5 using =  this.props.route.params.something

if(this.props.route.params.BackTopage == 'bookingpage'){ this.props.navigation.navigate('BookingPage') }

Comment: This is not working, it is forcibly redirecting to the home screen either if I use this above approach

Comment: Please show me your code...then i can get my point...theoretically is not possible to solve this problem ....show me your Route screen and the login approach thanks..